# Parsing a table from a dynamic web page into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-requests

I'm trying to parse a table from dynamic a web page into a Pandas dataframe. Employing a trick suggested in the answer to another Stackoverflow question ([HTTP Error 403: Forbidden when reading HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43590153/http-error-403-forbidden-when-reading-html/43590290#43590290)), I'm getting a response back. However, when I try and convert this into a Pandas DataFrame I get a `ParseError`. Any ideas?

Code, output and error below:

**Code:**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.barchart.com/options/volume-leaders/stocks"
header = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103 Safari/537.36",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
print("Encoding of response object is: ",r.encoding)
r_content = r.content
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(r_content.decode('utf-8')))
```

**Output from print() statement:**

```
Encoding of response object is:  UTF-8
```

**Error:**

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 12 fields in line 78, saw 219
```

Comment: Its not a csv file so you cannot use read_csv & it does not even contain any table to use ``read_html`` your best bet would be to use ``BeautifulSoup`` to extract the required details

Comment: I belive that pd.read_csv it is only able to read csv files. Maybe if you save "r_content" as a csv first, you'll can use this function...

Comment: Or, maybe, the problem is that the that the defalt separator of pd.read_csv is ",". Then it creates a new collumn for each comma. If you are using another character as separator you can try pd.read_csv([file name], sep="\t") if it is tab. If it is ";", you can use sep=";"