# Read table from website using pandas read_html

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping

I want to read the table from [this website](https://socialblade.com/youtube/top/category/news/mostviewed) using `pandas.read_html`. The site shows the top 100 most viewed News Channels on YouTube.

I tried to grab the table using pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html('https://socialblade.com/youtube/top/category/news/mostviewed')
```

However, it raises the following error:

> HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43590153/http-error-403-forbidden-when-reading-html), I pretended to be a browser, but the response's text does not seem to have a table:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://socialblade.com/youtube/top/category/news/mostviewed'
header = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}
df = pd.read_html(requests.get(url, headers=header).text)
```

> ValueError: No tables found

What is the easiest way to get this table into a `pandas.DataFrame` object?

Comment: `read_html()` - **Read HTML tables into a list of DataFrame objects.**  This function wont work because, like you said, there are no tables on the page. Its all formatted divs. You might have to get the html with requests like you are doing. Then get the relevant sections  you want using beautiful soup or something similar

Comment: I would just `beautifulsoup` and parse all the divs and spans that I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to scrap data from the site..
However, i would say you are using the wrong tool for this purpose, as if you closely see the html response of the site you are fetching, it do not have the html table tags.
Where as the pandas `read_html()` function seach for the `<table>` tags as stated in the pandas documentation here: - [https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html#:~:text=This%20function%20searches,into%20the%20header](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html#:%7E:text=This%20function%20searches,into%20the%20header)).

I would suggest you to use the correct tool for scrapping data using **Beautiful Soup**. It is a python library for doing scrapping of websites.