# How can I scrape all rows from a specific table?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I'm new to Python and Selenium and having the following problem:

I want to scrape certain columns from a table. The table is a table of the German Bundesliga and there are two buttons above it to change the season and the matchday. I want to scrape the data only for the 2021/22 season, but for all matchdays.

I managed to get all rows of the table for one matchday, but I don't know how to "iterate" over all matchdays.

I greatly appreciate any help on this!

Below is my last try. The result list only gives me the first 5 rows per matchday. I don't understand why and I'm running out of ideas how to correct my code. I'm not sure if it's a good idea to use xpath here, but I couldn't figure out another way to find the correct column entries (maybe, it's better to use class instead of xpath).

What I would expect is a list containing all rows of the first table on the page for all 34 matchdays (18 x 34 rows).

```
element_list = []
  
for matchday in range(1, 35, 1):
    
    url = 'https://www.kicker.de/bundesliga/tabelle/2021-22/' + str(matchday)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    position = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html[@class=' kick__nodark']/body/div[@id='kick__page-container']/div[@id='kick__page']/div[@class='kick__area--main']/div[@class='kick__card '][1]/div[@class='kick__data-grid']/div[@class='kick__data-grid__main ']/div[@class='kick__site-padding']/div[@id='1']/div[@class='kick__module-margin']/table[@class='kick__table kick__table--ranking kick__table--alternate kick__table--resptabelle']/tbody/tr/td[@class='kick__table--ranking__rank kick__respt-m-o-1 kick__respt-m-w-25']")
    team = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html[@class=' kick__nodark']/body/div[@id='kick__page-container']/div[@id='kick__page']/div[@class='kick__area--main']/div[@class='kick__card '][1]/div[@class='kick__data-grid']/div[@class='kick__data-grid__main ']/div[@class='kick__site-padding']/div[@id='1']/div[@class='kick__module-margin']/table[@class='kick__table kick__table--ranking kick__table--alternate kick__table--resptabelle']/tbody/tr/td[@class='kick__table--ranking__teamname kick__table--ranking__index kick__t__a__l kick__respt-m-o-4 kick__respt-m-w-120 kick__t__a__l']/a/span[@class='kick__table--show-desktop']")
    matchday = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html[@class=' kick__nodark']/body/div[@id='kick__page-container']/div[@id='kick__page']/div[@class='kick__area--main']/div[@class='kick__card '][1]/div[@class='kick__data-grid']/div[@class='kick__data-grid__main ']/div[@class='kick__site-padding']/div[@id='1']/div[@class='kick__module-margin']/table[@class='kick__table kick__table--ranking kick__table--alternate kick__table--resptabelle']/tbody/tr/td[@class='kick__table--ranking__number'][1]")
    goals = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html[@class=' kick__nodark']/body/div[@id='kick__page-container']/div[@id='kick__page']/div[@class='kick__area--main']/div[@class='kick__card '][1]/div[@class='kick__data-grid']/div[@class='kick__data-grid__main ']/div[@class='kick__site-padding']/div[@id='1']/div[@class='kick__module-margin']/table[@class='kick__table kick__table--ranking kick__table--alternate kick__table--resptabelle']/tbody/tr/td[@class='kick__table--ranking__number'][2]")
    points = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html[@class=' kick__nodark']/body/div[@id='kick__page-container']/div[@id='kick__page']/div[@class='kick__area--main']/div[@class='kick__card '][1]/div[@class='kick__data-grid']/div[@class='kick__data-grid__main ']/div[@class='kick__site-padding']/div[@id='1']/div[@class='kick__module-margin']/table[@class='kick__table kick__table--ranking kick__table--alternate kick__table--resptabelle']/tbody/tr/td[@class='kick__table--ranking__master kick__respt-m-o-5']")
  
    for i in range(len(team)):
        element_list.append([position[i].text, team[i].text, matchday[i].text, goals[i].text, points[i].text])
  
# closing the driver
driver.close()
```

Comment: what is the website?

Comment: The website is in the url variable. 

https://www.kicker.de/bundesliga/tabelle/2021-22/

Comment: Ah right, anyway you should put `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` before entering the for loop. Try and let me know

Comment: When I put that line of code before the for loop, I still end up with only the first 5 rows per matchday and the remaining 13 rows exist, but are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without selenium, I modified your code as follows for get the results you're looking for:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time as t

final_df = None # will contain the dataframe with all the data obtained

# Loop for make a request by each iteration - I've modified the "35" to "5" 
# for generate a shortened version of the desired results
for matchday in range(1, 5, 1):
  # Get the "table" HTML elements that exist on the page:  
  scrapper = pd.read_html('https://www.kicker.de/bundesliga/tabelle/2021-22/' + str(matchday))
  
  # In my tests, the 0 position is the one that contains the desired data:       
  for idx, table in enumerate(scrapper):
    if (idx == 0): 
      # Remove certain columns not needed: 
      table = table.drop(table.columns[[0, 1, 2]], axis=1)

      # Build the final dataframe - by initializing the variable 
      # or append the "table" to the final dataframe:
      if (final_df is None): 
        final_df = table
      else: 
        final_df = final_df.append(table, ignore_index=True)

# Display the final dataframe: 
display(final_df)
```

Results - *shortened*:

| index | Team | Sp. | ss-u-n | U | N | Tore | Diff. | Punkte |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Wolfsburg VfL Wolfsburg | 4 | 4-0-0 4 | 0 | 0 | 6:1 | 5 | 12 |
| 1 | Bayern (M) Bayern München (M) | 4 | 3-1-0 3 | 1 | 0 | 13:4 | 9 | 10 |
| 2 | Dortmund (P) Borussia Dortmund (P) | 4 | 3-0-1 3 | 0 | 1 | 13:9 | 4 | 9 |
| 3 | Mainz 1. FSV Mainz 05 | 4 | 3-0-1 3 | 0 | 1 | 6:2 | 4 | 9 |
| 4 | Freiburg SC Freiburg | 4 | 2-2-0 2 | 2 | 0 | 6:4 | 2 | 8 |
| 5 | Leverkusen Bayer 04 Leverkusen | 4 | 2-1-1 2 | 1 | 1 | 12:6 | 6 | 7 |
| 6 | Köln 1. FC Köln | 4 | 2-1-1 2 | 1 | 1 | 8:6 | 2 | 7 |
| 7 | Union 1. FC Union Berlin | 4 | 1-3-0 1 | 3 | 0 | 5:4 | 1 | 6 |
| 8 | Hoffenheim TSG Hoffenheim | 4 | 1-1-2 1 | 1 | 2 | 8:7 | 1 | 4 |
| 9 | Stuttgart VfB Stuttgart | 4 | 1-1-2 1 | 1 | 2 | 8:9 | -1 | 4 |
| 10 | Gladbach Bor. Mönchengladbach | 4 | 1-1-2 1 | 1 | 2 | 5:8 | -3 | 4 |
| 11 | Leipzig RB Leipzig | 4 | 1-0-3 1 | 0 | 3 | 5:6 | -1 | 3 |
| 12 | Bochum (N) VfL Bochum (N) | 4 | 1-0-3 1 | 0 | 3 | 4:6 | -2 | 3 |
| 13 | Bielefeld Arminia Bielefeld | 4 | 0-3-1 0 | 3 | 1 | 3:5 | -2 | 3 |
| 14 | Frankfurt Eintracht Frankfurt | 4 | 0-3-1 0 | 3 | 1 | 4:7 | -3 | 3 |
| 15 | Hertha Hertha BSC | 4 | 1-0-3 1 | 0 | 3 | 5:11 | -6 | 3 |
| 16 | Augsburg FC Augsburg | 4 | 0-2-2 0 | 2 | 2 | 1:8 | -7 | 2 |
| 17 | Fürth (N) SpVgg Greuther Fürth (N) | 4 | 0-1-3 0 | 1 | 3 | 2:11 | -9 | 1 |
| 18 | Stuttgart VfB Stuttgart | 1 | 1-0-0 1 | 0 | 0 | 5:1 | 4 | 3 |
| 19 | Hoffenheim TSG Hoffenheim | 1 | 1-0-0 1 | 0 | 0 | 4:0 | 4 | 3 |
| 20 | Dortmund (P) Borussia Dortmund (P) | 1 | 1-0-0 1 | 0 | 0 | 5:2 | 3 | 3 |
| 21 | Köln 1. FC Köln | 1 | 1-0-0 1 | 0 | 0 | 3:1 | 2 | 3 |
| 22 | Mainz 1. FSV Mainz 05 | 1 | 1-0-0 1 | 0 | 0 | 1:0 | 1 | 3 |
| 23 | Wolfsburg VfL Wolfsburg | 1 | 1-0-0 1 | 0 | 0 | 1:0 | 1 | 3 |

Comment: Thanks a lot! That‘s way more help than I expected. Just one more question: What‘s the headers variable for? I will mark your answer as correct once I‘ve tried it myself.

Comment: @Sarah the `header` variable is used in the requests you made to pretend to be a browser - as is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43590290/12511801). In my answer, I edited the answer due it's not need on this example.