# How do I retrieve the product title and price from the first Amazon result?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a Web Scraper using Beautiful Soup. As mentioned in the title, using Amazon, I am having difficulties with retrieving the product name and price from the first result.

Here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def submit_search():
    product_name = product_entry.get()
    product_page = requests.get(f"https://www.amazon.com/s?k={product_name}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(product_page.content, 'html.parser')

    price_element = soup.find(class_='a-price')
    if price_element is not None:
        price = float(price_element.text[1:])
        print(f"The price of the product is: ${price}")
    else:
        print("Could not find the price of the product")
```

An example output would be: *User enters "Apple" --> prints the price of the first result of Apple on Amazon*.
I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the class, but I'm not sure. If someone could assist me, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to add the header to your request to *pretend* to be a browser - as is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43590290/12511801).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the header to your request to *pretend* to be a browser - as is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43590290/12511801).

I've changed your code as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.parse

def submit_search():

  headers = {
        "User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36",
        "Referer": "https://www.amazon.com"
  }
  
  product_name = input("Enter product name: ")
  print(f"https://www.amazon.com/s?k={urllib.parse.quote(product_name)}")
  product_page = requests.get(f"https://www.amazon.com/s?k={urllib.parse.quote(product_name)}", headers=headers)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(product_page.content, 'html.parser')
  
  price_element = soup.find_all("span", class_="a-offscreen")

  if price_element is not None:
      price = price_element[0].get_text("", strip=True)
      print(f"The price of the product is: {price}")
  else:
      print("Could not find the price of the product")
```

Result:

```
Enter product name: apple
https://www.amazon.com/s?k=apple
The price of the product is: $25.00
```

Comment: Hey this works pretty well. However, do you know how I could account spaces? For example, if you try apple iPhone XR, it would only take input as "apple."

Comment: @Amogh_Spam then, you have to encode the search term, in this case, the `product_name` - see [here](https://www.urlencoder.io/python/) how - I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get a response from Amazon, you need to add the correct headers, otherwise, the page thinks that you a bot and will block you.

Also, to convert the price to a `float`, you should use:

```
price = float(price_element.text.split("$")[-1])
```

otherwise, youll get this as output:

```
'746.79$746.79'
```

and hence you won't be able to convert it to a *float* since it isn't a valid type.

So, try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def submit_search(product_name):
    HEADERS = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36",
        "referer": "https://www.amazon.com/",
    }
    product_page = requests.get(
        f"https://www.amazon.com/s?k={product_name}", headers=HEADERS
    )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(product_page.content, "html.parser")
    price_element = soup.find(class_="a-price")
    if price_element is not None:

        price = float(price_element.text.split("$")[-1])
        print(f"The price of the product is: ${price}")
    else:
        print("Could not find the price of the product")


submit_search("iphone")
```

Additionally, to get *all* the prices, you can try:

```py
def submit_search(product_name):
    HEADERS = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36",
        "referer": "https://www.amazon.com/",
    }
    product_page = requests.get(
        f"https://www.amazon.com/s?k={product_name}", headers=HEADERS
    )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(product_page.content, "html.parser")
    for product in soup.select('.a-section.a-spacing-base'):
        title = product.find("h2").text
        price = product.select_one(".a-price-whole,.a-offscreen").text
        print("{}\t\t\t{}".format(price, title))
```

Prints (truncated):

```
$454.00         Apple iPhone 12, 128GB, Black - Fully Unlocked (Renewed)  
$429.99         Apple iPhone 12 Mini, 64GB, Red - Unlocked (Renewed Premium)  
$432.00         Apple iPhone 12 Mini, 64GB, Blue - Unlocked (Renewed Premium)  
$617.00         Apple iPhone 12, 256GB, Green - Unlocked (Renewed Premium)  
$593.75         Apple iPhone 13, 128GB, Blue - Unlocked (Renewed)
```

---

Note, Amazon has a system for detecting bots, so you might still not get an output, hence, you should use a `try`/`except` to see wheter you get an output, as you'll get an `AttributeError`.